# load balancing between rolling and archive nodes

Tags: rpc

A possible deployment model for a Tezos RPC service is to distinguish requests between:

- requests that can be answered by a rolling node (injection, head block queries)
- historical requests that require an archive node (balance at level N)

What is a correct rule set to load balance between archive and rolling nodes, favoring rolling whenever possible?

Presumably:

- chains/main/blocks/head~+[0-9]*/* goes to rolling
- chains/main/blocks/[A-Za-z0-9]*/* goes to archive
- everything else goes to rolling

Will this work?

Comment: Rolling mode is typically the last 5 cycles (40,960 blocks).  How does your balancer/router grab the current HEAD value, N, and do pattern match against `if X > HEAD-40960 goto rolling else archive` It would have to be an actual proxy that can inspect current values then route with logic.

Comment: @utdrmac thanks, you are right, and that's not practical. As a consequence, my proposed rule above set would automatically route to archive whenever a block is queried by hash or number. Only `head` or `head~n` would go to the rolling node.